# Command + ` (backtick) not working when Stage Manager is on

Tags: macos-ventura

Command + ` (backtick) for switching between windows of the same app isn't working for me when Stage Manager is on.

Tried the steps at:

https://www.droidwin.com/command-tilde-shortcut-not-working-in-ventura-fix/

but I found that it would only work if I turn off Stage Manager.

Comment: I ran into the same thing and it seems to work differently than what their [documentation suggest](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213315): On most keyboards that have a character key to the left of the number 1, you can press that key together with the Command (⌘) key to quickly switch between the windows of the app you're using.

Comment: I'm finding basically the same thing. The shortcut will sometimes work initially, but then stop working after a few window switches. Most of the time it doesn't work at all. If you haven't use the Feedback Assistant to report this, I would do that.

Comment: Same here, i have submitted to feedback assistant.

Its so weird, for me it happens with Chrome, and its like there is a dead end of looping. Command-shift-backtick does the same thing, gets to this seemingly invisible window and once there you cannot tick in either direction.

FYI for me this happens with external display, or just with my macbook.

Comment: @mobob describes the issue that I am getting perfectly.

Comment: Yes seems to be a very much known issue with Stage Manager. It's like there is an invisible extra window in the stack that captures the focus and refuses to let go. Shame as I'm quite liking stage manager otherwise but this is forcing me to turn it off.

Comment: I don't know if it was the same in pre-ventura mac. But if you go to System Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts... -> Keyboard. The name for "command + `" is "Move focus to next window", instead of "Move focus to next window of the same application", making me wonder if this is intended feature, it all depends on what is defined as "next window"

Answer (score 2):

I found that if you have multiple monitors, each would be a separate 'stage' when Stage Manager is on. Command + `would switch among windows of the same app only if they are on the same stage. So if you have windows spread over different monitors, the key combo would not work. Turning off Stage Manager would make all monitors a single stage again and Command +` will work like it did before Ventura.